# Azure storage Cmdlet Rename-Blob wants an EndPoint

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm attempting to rename a blob to all lower case:

```
Rename-Blob -BlobUrl "https://ttseast.blob.core.windows.net/images/Add.png" -NewName "https://ttseast.blob.core.windows.net/images/add.png"
```

I've verified the blob URI by plugging it into a browser - however, attempting to execute the command tosses:

```
Rename-Blob : Blob URI does not correspond to storage account end point. A Blob URI must contain blob storage end point.
```

The arguments for Rename-Blob don't reference anything 'endpoint' - I've loaded the subscription so I should be authenticated and not forced to include AccountName/Key.

How to I determine (or set) the required end point?

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, I believe you're using [`Cerebrata Azure Management Cmdlets`](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/azure-management-cmdlets/features) as [`Windows Azure PowerShell Cmdlets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152841.aspx) do not have a `Rename-Blob` Cmdlet (Cerebrata has it).

To use Rename-Blob cmdlet, please try the following:

```
Rename-Blob -BlobUrl "https://ttseast.blob.core.windows.net/images/Add.png" -NewName "https://ttseast.blob.core.windows.net/images/add.png" -AccountName "ttseast" -AccountKey "<your accountkey>"
```

Comment: Just tried this out, for the new name, just add the name (without the http://..." part.